# Content Type Policy Templates - create programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention, information-policy

Is there a way to create **Content Type Policy Templates** through CSOM in SharePoint Online?
I don't mean applying a policy, but rather just creating the template for the policy, which can later be used by the users.

Here is [the article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-8CCAC9E4-3A50-49FA-A95B-D186032A6EE3) which explains how to do it as a user (check the first section - Create a policy for multiple content types within a site collection).